# Extracting the value represented by a particular set of bits in a number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, endianness

How to extract the value represented by a particular set of bits in a given number i.e. if bits 11,12 & 13 are 1,1,0 then the value should be 6.

What is the most efficient way of doing the same? Also, it should be generic. I should be able to give start and end bit positions and should be able to extract the value represented by the bits present between the start and end positions.

Ex: 
00000000 00000000 01100000 00011111

For the above number, considering 0th bit is from the right end, if I give this number,  0 as starting position and 2 as end position, then I should get the value 7.

Also, how do we take care of endianness also for the above problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
six = (value >> 12) & 7;
```

If you want to be generic,

```
inline unsigned extract_continuous_bits(unsigned value, int start, int end) {
    unsigned mask = (~0u) >> (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(value) - end - 1);
    return (value & mask) >> start;
}

assert(extract_continuous_bits(0x601f, 12, 14) == 6));
assert(extract_continuous_bits(0x601f, 0, 2) == 7));
assert(extract_continuous_bits(0xf0f0f0f0, 0, 31) == 0xf0f0f0f0));
assert(extract_continuous_bits(0x12345678, 16, 31) == 0x1234));
assert(extract_continuous_bits(0x12345678, 0, 15) == 0x5678));
```

And for endianness, see [When to worry about endianness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213441/when-to-worry-about-endianness).

Comment: I think (start+1) should just be start.  And in the OP's initial example, 11, 12, & 13 should actually be 14, 13, & 12 with start = 12 and end = 14.  That matches what they said later ("0th bit is from the right end")

Comment: @Matthew: That makes sense. Updated.

Comment: Be warned that this has an edge case - it' not guaranteed to work if `start` and `end` specify the full width of the type (here, `unsigned`).

Comment: Good point, caf.  That could be fixed with a special case.
   
if(end == (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - 1) && start == 0)
{
    return value;
}

Comment: OK I've updated the code so that it can handle `start=0`, `end=31` without special casing.